# DateRange on two columns and with one column for main condition

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime

Need little help with date range conditions for two columns along with one extra condition on third column, I want to to apply range query on two columns. It works fine if I don't put third column for one more condition along with date, but if I put the third column in condition then it is not giving me result as it must be,

My structure:

```
InDate datetime,
OutTime datetime,
payment nvarchar(10)
```

Following Query works fine with two column conditions

```
select * from  WEIGHT where 
Odate between '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' and '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999' 
or wdatetime between '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' and '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999' 
order by srno
```

But if i apply the third condition from third column it gives me wrong records

```
select * from  WEIGHT where 
Odate between '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' and '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999' 
or wdatetime between '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' and '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999'  
and Payment='ABC' 
order by srno
```

It must give records for satisfied conidtions but it is not,

I want to apply range query on two columns along with one extra condition from third column, I don't know why it's not working,

Comment: I recommend using parentheses to group your where conditions. For example from `select * from  WEIGHT where Odate between '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' and '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999' or wdatetime between '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' and '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999'  and Payment='ABC' order by srno` to `select * from  WEIGHT where (Odate between '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' and '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999' or wdatetime between '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' and '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999')  and (Payment='ABC') order by srno` Mixing [or] and [and] in a where clause without parenthesis usually causes confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The `AND` operator takes precedence over the `OR` operator.  Your query is effectively

`X OR (Y AND Z)`

when what you want is

`(X OR Y) AND Z`

Even if they're not strictly required, which they are in this case, I would suggest always using parentheses for clarity when mixing `AND` and `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write a subquery.

```
Select sub.*(
   SELECT * FROM Weight WHERE 
    ODATE BETWEEN '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' AND '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999' 
    OR 
    WDATETIME BETWEEN '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' AND '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999'
)sub 
WHERE  sub.Payment = 'ABC' ORDER BY SRNO
```

Basically this will run the date selection first, and then run the payment selection from those results.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from  WEIGHT where (Odate between '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' and '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999' or wdatetime between '19/Dec/2016 00:00:00.000' and '19/Dec/2016 23:59:59.999')  and Payment='ABC' order by srno
```

please try this